# How convert opus/ogg file to telegram voice format?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to send voice message thorough SendVoice method but it sends the voice as a simple ogg file.

Please help me with how to fix (convert) the file and make sure that the first file (test1.ogg) is uploaded as a voice message to telegram and not as an audio file.

[an example of how it looks on android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgJjL.jpg)

> `ffmpeg -i C:\FFmpeg\test.mp3 -ac 1 -map 0:a -codec:a opus -b:a 128k -vbr off -strict -2 C:\FFmpeg\test.ogg`

What is my mistake? Both files have been converted to opus.ogg

But one file is displayed as a voice message, and the other is just an audio file.

My ogg file : https://cloud.mail.ru/public/42WZ/TTX23SfAa

The most interesting thing is that if you take the second file "test2.ogg" and convert it to another format, but then return it to opus again, it will calmly display as a voice message. But "test1.ogg" will always be displayed as an audio file no matter what you do with it.